# Rotate geometry to align to a direction vector

Tags: c++, 3d, geometry, rotational-matrices, glm-math

I've been trying to get my generated geometry to align with a direction vector. To illustrate what my current problem is:

- A = Correctly aligned geometry ( just a triangle for testing )
- B = Incorrectly aligned geometry

[image: Example of the problem]

My current solution in code for this triangle example (This code is run for all the nodes you see on screen starting at the split, I am using the GLM math library):

```
glm::vec3 v1, v2, v3;

v1.x = -0.25f; 
v1.z = -0.25f; 

v2.x = 0.25f;
v2.z = -0.25f;

v3.x = 0.0f; 
v3.z = 0.25f;

v1.y = 0.0f;
v2.y = 0.0f;
v3.y = 0.0f;

glm::mat4x4 translate = glm::translate(glm::mat4x4(1.0f), sp.position);
glm::mat4x4 rotate = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), sp.direction, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));

v1 = glm::vec4(translate * rotate * glm::vec4(v1, 1.0f)).swizzle(glm::comp::X, glm::comp::Y, glm::comp::Z);
v2 = glm::vec4(translate * rotate * glm::vec4(v2, 1.0f)).swizzle(glm::comp::X, glm::comp::Y, glm::comp::Z);
v3 = glm::vec4(translate * rotate * glm::vec4(v3, 1.0f)).swizzle(glm::comp::X, glm::comp::Y, glm::comp::Z);
```

The direction vector values for point A:

- x 0.000000000 float
- y 0.788205445 float
- z 0.615412235 float

The direction vector values for point B:

- x 0.0543831661 float
- y 0.788205445 float
- z -0.613004684 float

**Edit 1 (24/11/2013 @ 20:36)**:
A and B do not have any relation, both are generated separately. When generating A or B only a position and direction is known.

I've been looking at solutions posted here:

- [Quaternions, rotate a model and align with a direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258413/quaternions-rotate-a-model-and-align-with-a-direction)
- [Direct3D
  Rotation Matrix from Vector and vice-versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874087/direct3d-rotation-matrix-from-vector-and-vice-versa)
- [Direction Vector To
  Rotation Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558910/direction-vector-to-rotation-matrix)

But I haven't been able to successfully rotate my geometry to align with my direction vector. I feel like I'm doing something rather basic wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If `A` and `B` are unit vectors and you want a rotation matrix `R` that transforms `B` so that it aligns with `A`, then start by computing `C = B x A`  (the cross-product of `B` and `A`).  `C` is the axis of rotation, and `arcsin(|C|)` is the necessary rotation angle.

From these you can build the required rotation matrix. It looks like `glm` has support for this, so I won't explain further.

NB if you are doing many, many of these in performance-critical code, you can gain a bit of speed by noting `|C| = sin(theta), sqrt(1 - |C|^2) = cos(theta)` and computing the matrix yourself with these known values of `sin(theta)` and `cos(theta)`.  For this see for example [this discussion](http://inside.mines.edu/fs_home/gmurray/ArbitraryAxisRotation/).  The `glm` routine will take your angle `arcsin(|C|)` and proceed immediately to compute its `sin` and `cos`, a small waste since you already knew these and the operations are relatively expensive.

If the rotation is about some point `p` other than the origin, then let `T` be a translation that takes `p` to the origin, and find `X = T^-1 R T`.  This `X` will be the transformation you want.

Comment: The issue here is that A & B have no relation and cannot be used in this way. When generating the triangle at point A or B only a position and direction are known. I will clarify my question at the top to include this.

Comment: @Yonathan my friend, this makes absolutely no sense. You must explain what point and vector must be translated and/or rotated to some other point and vector (or equivalent description of transformation).

Comment: When generating the triangle at point A or point B I only have a translation (position) and a direction it should be facing. Translation works fine as you can see the triangles are both located on the dark gray dot. The lighter gray line indicates the direction the face should point towards. What I am trying to accomplish is having these triangles on every gray dot, facing the next gray dot. This to at some point generate geometry along these points which correctly aligns. Therefor I want to generate a matrix to correctly rotate the vertices of this geometry. Hopefully this makes more sense.

Comment: @Yonathan Then my answer applies.  If you have a triangle with a normal vector that's wrong (A), and you have two points that describe a hormal vector that's right (B), then you need a rotation that takes A to B.  That's what I described.

Comment: You can also use `(A•B)/(|A||B|)` to get the cosine, since the dot product of two unit vectors is the cosine of the angle between them.